# SailsJS test boiler plate for newbies (new port, new database, drop database, fixtures)

Tags: unit-testing, sails.js

I followed the guide here - https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/testing

New to Node.js backend. (Frontend guy here)

However the docs on testing are real sparse. Is there any boilerplate to make it use a clean database, and then drop the database after tests are done, and that it runs on a seperate port then default 1337 so it doesn't collide.

I know i can write this stuff myself, but it just seems that there should be some boilerplate to use, I can't find any. The only one I found is this and its real complicated - https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/blob/master/test/private/before.js - none of it is explained.